# Firebase looping over the child views for populating spinners - android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

[image: Database tree]

What I want to get is "Kasarwadi" and similar node that will be added after. I have to populated spinner with this data. How can I loop over to get this?

Also when I tried to loop over in the event Listeners, foreach loop is not getting executed or  I can say control is not getting transferred in foreach (enhanced for loop)loop.

***code for ref`***

```
         DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("people-3999c");
       mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("STATE"," inside ondataChange");

                for (DataSnapshot location : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d("STATE","1");
                    locationFromFB.add(location.getKey());
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,locationFromFB);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            Log.d("STATE","outside");

        }`
```

Comment: Why don't you set the spinner adapter once you get the whole data  in a ArrayList (outside the for loop) ?

Comment: Yes, but this won't help with the problem

Comment: Try this :- bind data to adapter in separate method and call the method after for loop pass the array list as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use that `locationFromFB` ArrayList you need to declare it inside `onDataChange()` method, otherwise is null, due the asynchronous behaviour.

Get also the following line ouf of the for loop because you are creating a new instance every time the for loop iterates.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,locationFromFB);
```

Please change also the `DatabaseReference` like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("Kasarwadi").child("Users");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did as you said but data from the database is not showing up. Infact the Log statement in for loop is not getting printed in the logcat.

Comment: See my updated answer. One more thing, please share the correct database strcuture. In Firebase everything is structured as pair of key and value. You cannot have only keys like you posted,(Available, Available, Available)

Comment: Yes I was wrongly setting the root reference as below:

`DatabaseReference rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("people-399c");`  as I thought this may work work fine.

`Rootref` doesn't need string in `getReference()` method.

Also now when I place `locationFromFB` outside `onDataChange()` , it still works fine. Thanks